# Swift UI Image does not clip to bounds

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an image url that I present using the King fisher library. When I set a maxHeight to the image and clip it I can still click on the image outside of the frame. It's as if the image is not actually clipped but the rest of the image is hidden. How do I get the image to respect the frame? Clicking on somewhere below or above the image will cause the print to execute.

```
import SwiftUI
import Kingfisher

struct SwiftUIView: View {
   
   var body: some View {
       VStack {
           Spacer()
           KFImage(URL(string: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/hustle-85b6c.appspot.com/o/groupChats%2F4A0FFF47-A99C-4571-8EA7-014E6D2E94FB?alt=media&token=856102c8-119c-448f-9f6b-6979a540729f"))
               .resizable()
               .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
               .frame(maxHeight: 250)
               .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16))
               .onTapGesture {
                   print("Hi")
               }
           Spacer()
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like any `clipped` will not prevent content from being tapped. You may want to try this approach:

```swift
KFImage(URL(string: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/hustle-85b6c.appspot.com/o/groupChats%2F4A0FFF47-A99C-4571-8EA7-014E6D2E94FB?alt=media&token=856102c8-119c-448f-9f6b-6979a540729f"))
   .resizable()
   .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
   .frame(maxHeight: 250)
   .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16))
   .contentShape(Rectangle()) //<- here
   .onTapGesture {
       print("Hi")
   }
```